Identify this SOT23-5 chip with marking 5AG1R
I have a MSI GF66 11UE laptop that burned one of its SOT23-5 chip. I was able to find out that it is labeled as 5AG1R. Can anyone help me decode this so I can replace this chip with something similar?


Please reverse engineer the schematic and post what you can.

Possible match: G517G1TO1U (https://cdn.badcaps-static.com/pdfs/92bb3f5ab5cc827e333bd06d6855822d.pdf)
Hard to tell, but pinout seems to make sense. 1 and 5 look like big power rails, double-check pin 2 goes to GND. R is probably the date code.

Seems to me, it’s a battery voltage monitor. RP124N303E. https://www.nisshinbo-microdevices.co.jp/en/pdf/datasheet/rp124-ea.pdf

Here is a post on badcaps about the same component.

It's possibly a GMT G517G1TO1U power distribution switch.


(Source: aliexpress.com)
This post on badcaps describes a similar IC. It's not conclusively identified there, but the G517G1TO1U was mentioned as one possibility.
